# How to use draggable on overflow:scroll containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have this item that I want to drag to another container, but after scroll the first item stays down the mouse while dragging and the first container resets to the top.

Edit. This is an updated 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGhCj/7/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id=left>
    <div id=item>drag me!</div>
</div>
<div id=right></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:50%;
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    right:0;
    background-color:green;
}
#item{
    position:static;
    top:150px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#left #item").draggable({
    revert: true,
    stack:"#right",
    start: function() { $(this).parent().css('overflow-y', 'visible'); },
    stop: function() { $(this).parent().css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); }
    //helper:"clone"
});
$("#right").droppable({
    tolerance:"pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(".tmp").remove();
        $("<div>").appendTo(this)
            .addClass("new")
            .css("background-color","blue")
            .css("height","20px");
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $("<div>").appendTo(this)
            .addClass("tmp")
            .css("border","2px dashed black")
            .css("height","20px");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(".tmp").remove();
    }
});
```

I did my best to resume the code to reproduce the bug since its a very large project, so I hope this way someone can help me.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out.  It seems the scroll really messes things up.  I have a partial solution http://jsfiddle.net/YGhCj/2/.  I change the scroll css attribute when dragging.  I don't trust it, however.

Comment: @Daniel it works perfect! I could accept this as an answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Actually I'm not going to put this as an answer.  It'll bug out later.  Don't do it this way.  If you've triggered the overflow scrolling and the `start` event fires, it's going to distort your page because the entire overflow area will overlap the elements below.